# Google Maps Api3, removing places

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How to remove from Maps (Google API 3) all the places like goverments, shops e.g.?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [styled map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling). Turn off POI labels.

```
[
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  }
]
```